# Cloning Mongoid document in ruby on rails from one tenant to another tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-6, apartment-gem

I am using `ruby 2.7` and `rails 6.0.3.2`, `mongoid gem 7.1.0` with `ros-paartment gem 2.7.2`.
What I am trying to do?
I have different tenants created using `ros-apartment gem`. I have populated data on admin tenant. In admin tenant, I have around 12 DB tables, here DB used is `mongo`. Now What I want is whenever a new tenant is created, I want to copy all the content of a few tables from admin tenant to newly created tenant. Suppose, say I have 12 tables, I want to populate 9 tables to newly created tenant from admin tenant. Is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: Mongoid supports using multiple clients out of the box. No additional libraries are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could try is

```
after_create_tenant :copy_from_admin_tenant


def copy_from_admin_tenant
 data = Apartment::Tenant.switch('admin_tenant') { admin_data = Model.all.as_json}
 data.each {|x| Model.create(x)}
end
```